# JQuery attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the following is my HTML DOM element...

```
<input type="text" style="width: 200px;" id="input1"/>
```

I want to keep the date value in it..But somewhere i need to specify that it is going to hold date value in the Dom element..

How can i do so..Please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to hide data inside the control.
An easier way would be to assign a css class to the element.

and jquery has lots of methods for retrieving the class names out of an element.

Or you could go with the html 5 standard for adding data like this:

```
<input id='ctrl' type='text' data-attr='date' />
```

Then you can retrieve the attribute value like this:

```
var value = $("#ctrl").attr("data-attr");
```

Answer (score 3):

JQuery is returning the runtime type of the input element from the DOM.  Since "date" isn't a valid type for a form input, it is returning the default value : "text".

These are the valid input types:

```
* "text"
* "password"
* "checkbox"
* "radio"
* "submit"
* "reset"
```

If you try the same code snippet with one of the above instead of "date", it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to w3c standard there are no input controls with "date" type. Check it on W3C [Forms in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

What does it display instead?

It could be that date is a non standard form type. I think it is coming in HTML 5, but currently it is not supported.

Could you accidentally have 2 elements with that Id ? That code looks like it should work.

Try this

```
$("#input1").css( {border: '1px solid red'} );
```

To ensure it is matching the right element. If the correct element doesn't gain a red border, then your selector is probably incorrect.